# how to convert varchar to bigint in mysql

Tags: mysql

```
DECLARE a_varchar_variable varchar(20) DEFAULT "999999999999999";
DECLARE a_biginteger_variable BIGINT;
```

In my mysql stored procedure, this is working fine:

```
a_biginteger_variable = CONVERT(a_varchar_variable,UNSIGNED INT);
```

On the other hand, This gives a syntax error:

```
a_biginteger_variable = CONVERT(a_varchar_variable,BIGINT);
```

I would like to understand what causes this behavior. and how to convert varchar to bigint?

It seems to be a repeating question on google but no answer found. which is weird because I though it should be easy.

Comment: no. `int` is a 32bit value, `bigint` is 64bit. You cannot reliably compare them, doubly so when doing unsigned v.s. signed. And your syntax errors is due to `bigint not being a valid conversion target: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html#function_convert

Comment: thanks for your fast answer. I still don't get what should be done if I want to convert varchar to bigint. I couldn't find anything on google which is weird because I thought it should be easy.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Mainly, I needed to change varchar to int because i wanted to loop over a certain variable..

I tried adding 1 on varchar as a solution and it worked fine in the loop

```
a_varchar_variable = a_varchar_variable + 1
```

Comment: After a long struggle, I had to settle on this hack.

Comment: it is too hacky way

Answer (score 4):

`a_biginteger_variable = CAST(a_varchar_variable as SIGNED INTEGER);`

Usually it return a bigint.